# How to update an object that comes from a Play Framework 2.0 form using Spring+JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, playframework-2.0

I am currently using Play Framework 2.10 + Spring and JPA. I didn't use Ebeans because in future versions of Play it will be deprecated, [as stated here](http://www.jensjaeger.com/2013/11/play-framework-2-ebean-vs-jpa/).

I am trying to update an object that comes from my database, it is changed in a Play form, and comes back to be updated. The problem is that each time I save the object using its Spring Repository it creates a new entity. My controller code appears below.

```
package controllers;

import model.Doctor;
import repositories.DoctorRepository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import play.data.Form;
import play.mvc.Result;
import views.html.doctores.blank;
import views.html.doctores.show;

@Controller
public class Doctores {
    @Autowired
    public DoctorRepository doctorRepository;

    private static final Form<Doctor> doctorForm = Form.form(Doctor.class);


    public Result save() {
        Form<Doctor> boundForm = doctorForm.bindFromRequest();
        if (boundForm.hasErrors()) {
            return play.mvc.Controller.badRequest(blank.render(boundForm));
        }

        Doctor doctor = boundForm.get();
        doctorRepository.save(doctor);
        return play.mvc.Controller.redirect(routes.Doctores.list());
    }


    public Result show(Long id) {
        final Doctor doctor = doctorRepository.findOne(id);
        if (doctor == null) {
            return play.mvc.Controller.notFound(String.format("Doctor %s no existe.", id));
        }

        Form<Doctor> filledForm = doctorForm.fill(doctor);
        return play.mvc.Controller.ok(show.render(filledForm));
    }
}
```

I don't want to temporally store the object in the Play's cache or session, restore it, and manually find out what attributes changed. How can I update my object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the merge() method.

```
Doctor doctor = boundForm.get();
doctor.merge();
return play.mvc.Controller.redirect(routes.Doctores.list());
```

Make sure the doctor object has primary key field set. This can be achieved, for example, by adding hidden field to the form.

Comment: Does this address the 'problem' of you don't wanting certain fields to be changed?

i.e. imagine you have:

FieldA
FieldB

FieldNoChangesPlease

And on your form you only want to allow FieldA and FieldB to be changed.
Wouldn't that code leave FieldNoChangesPlease blank? (if you didn't include it in the form)